# laravel pass in optional form values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel and trying to figure out how to do the following:

I have a route that looks like this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

and it uses a query like this:

```
public function show()
{
    $users = DB::select('select * from users WHERE Active = "Y"');
    return View::make('users.show')->with('users', $users);
}
```

And it shows fine. But above the results of the view, I have a form that allows someone to search by say first name or last name. I can not figure out how to do this in laravel. I am not sure if I need a different function that will expect those optional search parameters or if I can use the show function and just check for values?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel strips all GET query parameters (`/user?name=John`) for security reasons, so you either have to use POST or pass them as route parameters (`/user/John`).

Using POST you'll have access to [Input](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#basic-input). You'll be able to provide default values like this:

```
Route::post('user', function()
{
    return Input::get('name', 'John');
});
```

For [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) you'll be able to define optional parameters like this:

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function($name = 'John')
{
    return $name;
});
```

You won't be able to use resource controllers with this, as they don't allow you to define custom endpoints, just the basic [GET/POST by ID ones](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

I know you don't like defining route handlers in the route definitions.
There's [RESTful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) for that.

Comment: So would I need to move that $users = DB::select ... into the route then? I am not sure how this flow would work. I want it to display all the users, but then filter on last name if submit button is selected.

Comment: As I said, check out RESTful controllers. That way you won't have to write your functions in the same place you define the routes.

Comment: I have all my functions in my controller 
class UsersController extends BaseController {
} but I am still not clear on how I would use that same show() function to accept optional form values if the user chooses to search by first or last name. Laravel is much different than I am used to as you can tell.

Comment: Well, you have a _resource_ controller. You won't be able to add any parameters to the methods in there nor change the routes to add parameters. Laravel supports multiple ways of defining routes and controller endpoints though, and the one I find fitting in your situation is using a RESTful controller. Please read the documentation about them here http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers

Comment: thanks so much, I appreciate you pointing me in the right direction